# Moq - Simple Cache Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm just starting with Moq and unit testing in general.  What I'm trying to do here is create a simple test to make sure my caching functionality is working correctly.

Why does the following test fail? The test is failing because the repository is getting called twice. However, I have stepped through the debugger and verified that the second call does pull from the cache and does not query the repository.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Cache()
    {
var Service = new Service(_mockRepository.Object, _mockLogger.Object, _mockCacheStorage.Object);

Service.GetAll();
Service.GetAll();

_mockRepository.Verify(r => r.FindAll(), Times.Once());
}
```

**Update**

Here is the service code, which I have verified works through the debugger.

```
public IList<Csa> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            string cacheKey = "GetAll";

            IList<Csa> activeList = _cacheStorage.Get<List<Csa>>(cacheKey);

            if (activeList == null)
            {
                activeList = _Repository.FindAll();
                _cacheStorage.Set(cacheKey, activeList);
            }

            return activeList;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Log(LogType.Error, exception.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code for Service?

Comment: @CRice I updated my original post.

Comment: you appear to have mocked everything out. What are you testing?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - I'm trying to test that the call to the repository is only done once when the service method is called twice.  The second call should retrieve from the cache, not the repository, which I've verified works through the debugger, however, I'm trying to get my head around mocking and unit testing.

Comment: @Beavis - Is this the first test you've written that covers this method?

Comment: It appears that you are using a Moq object that got created outside of your method. Is it possible that another unit test in the same class is running, and causing the mocked repository method to get called before this method even begins?

Comment: Also, I can imagine your _mockCacheStorage mock potentially accessing the repository. Could you please include the code that shows how your mocks are initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to break up your testing into two seperate tests. One test should verify that the Repository is accessed when the activeList is null, and the other test should verify that the fetch from the repository is skipped when the activeList is not null. The key is to 'stub' the _cacheStorage.Get<> call in the skipped version.

Something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Cache()
{
    var Service = new Service(_mockRepository.Object, _mockLogger.Object, _mockCacheStorage.Object);

    _mockCacheStorage.SetupGet(g => g.Get<List<Csa>>(It.IsAny<string>).Returns(new List<Csa>());

    Service.GetAll();

    _mockRepository.Verify(r => r.FindAll(), Times.Never());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a problem with your mock cache storage always returning null.  You are mocking the cache storage, so my guess is that calls to Get and Set on your cached storage aren't saving off the list properly.  You have a few options:

- mock get and set on your mock cache storage to get and set a local variable or dictonary
- create a stub implementation of your cache storage interface that just uses a dictionary underneath
- don't inject a dependency for your cache storage and just use a dictionary in your implementation.